# Transaction weight/size understanding

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc, transaction-fees, transaction-size

According to Monero source code there are two metrics for the transaction size:

- `Size` https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/v0.17.2.0/src/wallet/wallet2.cpp#L870
- `Weight` https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/v0.17.2.0/src/wallet/wallet2.cpp#L878

There is Wallet RPC method returning them both `estimate_tx_size_and_weight`: https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/v0.17.2.0/src/wallet/wallet2.cpp#L14187 and https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/v0.17.2.0/src/wallet/wallet_rpc_server.cpp#L4317

I'm trying to understand how that metrics are related to real transaction size, for example:

- https://localmonero.co/blocks/tx/82966ee2ade89b159b80bc376b608cc9e8e8cd3b5206abcac267984414fee8f0 real size: 1452 estimated size: 1460 weight: 1460 - both differs by 8 bytes
- https://localmonero.co/blocks/tx/46a36725ed36e624fc8de94ed79943284639d4e524d600b0367297f7c575bc01 real size: 1966 estimated size: 1969 weight: 1969 - both differ by 3 bytes
- https://localmonero.co/blocks/tx/de4b645e96be1d98b2e753a450b433b5ab2916c2911c0a4a6736cbe43a4624bf real size: 3700 but estimated **size: 3253 weight: 7221** - it seems no size and no weight are related to real size because so big difference

What's wrong with the estimation or maybe I don't understand some logic behind?

Answer (score 1):

In your 1st and 2nd examples, where the difference is tiny, you're talking about a few bytes difference between *estimated* and actual *size*. I'd expect to see this due to things like varints. Also, weight and size estimates for these match because the bulletproof *clawback* isn't being calculated/applied due to there only being 2 outputs on those txs.

In your 3rd example, you're seeing a big difference between *estimated* weight and *real* size because this tx has 16 outputs, hence you're seeing the bulletproof *clawback* come into play on the *weight* estimate. Also, you're seeing the several hundred bytes difference between real and estimate *size* because that tx has a tx_extra field which is 547 bytes in size and the estimation only uses the common case of tx_extra being 44 bytes in size.